# Issue while extracting table data using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The code below gives me the required product data as a table. It works fine for most links, however in some it stops midway giving an error `NoneType` object has no attribute `find_all` in `table.find_all('tr)`.

I believe this is because table does not exist in some products, so I tried creating an if condition on the existence of the table, but that also doesn't seem to help. What changes should I make in the code below?

```
import requests, json, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/toilet-accessories/?p="
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

data = []

for i in range(1,3):
    print(i)
    res = requests.get(url + str(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    p_links = [i["data-link"] for i in soup.find("ul", {"id":"products-list"}).find_all("li",class_=["openlink","item"])]

    for prod_url in p_links:
        print(prod_url)
        temp = {"Product URL": prod_url}
        prod_res = requests.get(prod_url, headers = headers)
        prod_soup = BeautifulSoup(prod_res.text, "html.parser")

        for p in prod_soup.find("div", class_="basic-information").find_all("p"):
            if "item" in p.text.lower(): temp["item number"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
            elif "brand" in p.text.lower(): temp["manufacturer"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
            elif "sku" in p.text.lower(): temp["sku"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
    
        table = prod_soup.find("table",{"class":"specifications"})
        for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
            temp[tr.find("td", {"class":"tdLabel"}).text.strip()] = tr.find("td", {"class":"tdValue"}).text.strip()
        data.append(temp)
        

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("toilet-acc.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this:

```
tables = soup.select('table', attrs={"class":"specifications"})
rows = tables.findChildren(['tr'])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Try` and `Except` ([documentation)](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html):

```
try:
    for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
        temp[tr.find("td", {"class":"tdLabel"}).text.strip()] = tr.find("td", {"class":"tdValue"}).text.strip()
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests, json, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.1800wheelchair.com/category/toilet-accessories/?p="
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}

data = []

for i in range(1,3):
    print(i)
    res = requests.get(url + str(i), headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
    p_links = [i["data-link"] for i in soup.find("ul", {"id":"products-list"}).find_all("li",class_=["openlink","item"])]

    for prod_url in p_links:
        print(prod_url)
        temp = {"Product URL": prod_url}
        prod_res = requests.get(prod_url, headers = headers)
        prod_soup = BeautifulSoup(prod_res.text, "html.parser")
        try:
            for p in prod_soup.find("div", class_="basic-information").find_all("p"):
                if "item" in p.text.lower(): temp["item number"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
                elif "brand" in p.text.lower(): temp["manufacturer"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
                elif "sku" in p.text.lower(): temp["sku"] = p.find("span").text.strip()
        
            table = prod_soup.find("table",{"class":"specifications"})
            for tr in table.find_all("tr"):
                temp[tr.find("td", {"class":"tdLabel"}).text.strip()] = tr.find("td", {"class":"tdValue"}).text.strip()
        except:
            print("Failed for URL {}".format(prod_url))
        data.append(temp)
        time.sleep(2)
        

pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv("toilet-acc.csv", index=False)
```

Put a `try/except` not only to extract product specification but also to extract item/brand/sku. But in the except put a print statement to know which all urls failed so that you can try them again